# Loading js files in Watir

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, automation, watir

I want to be able to dynamically load .js libraries like jquery using Watir for some advanced browser automation. This is what I tried:

```
$browser.execute_script( %{var bootscript = document.createElement("script");
      bootscript.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
      bootscript.setAttribute("src", "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js");
      document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(bootscript);
     alert('I loaded jquery!');});
```

**Update** no longer crashing after a typo was fixed. Still getting errors when using jquery functions.

Answer (score 1):

The exception occurs because there is an error while executing the javascript. If you check the page, you will see a javascript error like:

```
Message: 'script' is undefined
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
```

If you add the script line by line, you will see that the error is occurring on the line:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
```

The problem is that there is a typo in your variable. You are using `script` instead of your defined `bootscript`. Doing the following will no longer throw the exception:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(bootscript);
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing the typo. Still having some problems using jquery functions once it loads. I'll update as soon as I figure out what is wrong. Need to test on a fresh page.